# (Real Analysis) How to prove this one?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L$.

a. If $L<1$, prove that the sequence ${a_n}$ converges and that $lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=0$

b. If $L>1$, prove that the sequence ${a_n}$ is unbounded.

I was trying to prove "a" by using the theorem that the sequence is bounded if it is convergent sequence.

But I'm not sure if this is right..

Could you please give me some hints on these problems?

Comment: look up "ratio test" on Google.

Answer (score 0):

If $L < 1$ then 
$L < (1+L)/2 < 1$.
Let $c
= (1+L)/2$
so for $n > n(c)$
$a_{n+1}/a_n < c$.

Since $c^m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$,
for $m > 0, n > n(c)$
we have
$a_{n+m}/a_n < c^m$
so $a_{n+m} \to 0$.

Similarly, for $L >. 1$,
$a_{n+1}/a_n > c$
for large enough $n$
so  $a_{n+m} \to \infty$.